# sending values to url string on dropdown selected value change in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have two tables. First is Development region and second is Zone. Zone has got RegionID as a foreign key. I would like to populate all the row from Zone table that is related with the Region selected from the dropdown list. I cannot figure out why the value is not being passed in url string. Please help me out and suggest the best way to accomplish it. Below are the models, controllers and view.

Model Zone

```
public class Zone
{
    [Key]
    public int ZoneID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Zone Code")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]*$"), StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Code cannot be more than 5 charachter long")]
    [Column("ZCode")]
    public string ZoneCode { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Zone"),RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-z]*$"),Required]
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public virtual DevRegion devregion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Active")]
    public Boolean isActive { get; set; }
}
```

Model DevRegions

```
public class DevRegion
{
    [Key]
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]*$"), StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Code cannot be more than 5 charachter long")]
    [Column("RCode")]
    public string RegionCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Region")]
    [Column("RName")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s-]*$", ErrorMessage ="Region can only consist of alphabets, space and dash")]
    [StringLength(30,ErrorMessage ="Region cannot exceed 30 characters")]
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Active")]
    public Boolean  isActive { get; set; }
}
```

ZonesController

```
public class ZonesController : Controller
{
    private HuRISContext db = new HuRISContext();

    // GET: Zones
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.RegionID = new SelectList(db.DevRegions, "RegionID", "RegionName");
        var zones = db.Zones.Include(z => z.devregion).Where(x=>x.RegionID==(int)(id??x.RegionID));
        return View(zones.ToList());
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<HuRIS.Models.Zone>
....
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Zones",FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group center-block">
                <label for="RegionID" class="control-label">Region:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("RegionID", null, "Show all Zones", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.devregion.RegionName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZoneCode)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZoneName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isActive)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.devregion.RegionName</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZoneCode)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZoneName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isActive)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ZoneID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ZoneID }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ZoneID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form-control").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "~/ZonesController/Index",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { RegionID: $(".form-control").val() },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i want to populate data from the table "Zone" depending upon the value selected from the Region dropdown. I wanted to send the selected value to url string which then would call the index method and populate data from the zone table whose RegionID=id-from-urlstring.

Answer (score 0):

index method as shown below

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Region = new SelectList(db.DevRegions, "RegionID", "RegionName");
        var allzones = db.Zones.Include(z => z.devregion);
        return View(allzones.ToList());
    }
```

create new method as Shown below to accept the id selected on dropdown change event and create the partial view to load on the list of data from the table depending on what is selected on the dropdown:

```
public ActionResult ZoneList(int? id)
    {
        var zones = db.Zones.Include(z => z.devregion).Where(x => x.RegionID == (int)(id ?? x.RegionID));
        return PartialView("~/Views/PartialViews/_ZoneList.cshtml", zones.ToList());
    }
```

changed javascript as follows.

```
 $("#Region").change(function () {

    var selectedID = $(this).val();

    $.get('/Zones/ZoneList/' + selectedID, function (data) {
        $('.table').html(data);
        //$('.table').fadeOut("linear");
        //$('.table').fadeIn("linear");
    });
});
});
```

on the index.cshtml changed the code as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<HuRIS.Models.Zone>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group center-block">
            <label for="RegionID" class="control-label">Region:</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("Region", null, "Show all Zones", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@{ 
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViews/_ZoneList.cshtml", Model);
}
```

partial view _ZoneList.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<HuRIS.Models.Zone>

<table class="table">

    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.devregion.RegionName)

    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZoneCode)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ZoneName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isActive)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.devregion.RegionName)

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZoneCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ZoneName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isActive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ZoneID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ZoneID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ZoneID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```